# Verify if a list (or a sublist of that list) of decimal values can equal a certain sum

Tags: c#, linq, algorithm, list

Hi I have a `List<decimal>` containing values between ]0;1].
I want to check if a total (or subtotal) of these values can equal 1 (or almost).

I can also use `Linq` functions to filter or manipulate the list.

Desired results:

- A list containing {0.7, 0.7, 0.7} should return false;
- A list containing {0.7, 0.3, 0.7} should return true;
- A list containing {0.777777, 0.2, 0.1} should return false;
- A list containing {0.33333, 0.33333, 0.33333} should return true;
- A list containing {0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.3} should return true.

Obviously, I'll want something with the lowest performance cost possible.

Comment: This might be best solved by a [flow network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_network)

Comment: Thank you NominSim but, does a simpler algorithm exists?

Comment: To brute force you will need all permutations summed, of which there will be N! It will get expensive quickly without something a little more fancy me thinks.

Comment: @AdamMills Brute force is N*2^N, not N!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATED -- now doesn't repetively sum
try this

```
bool isClose(IEnumerable<decimal> list, decimal epislon) {
  return isClose(Enumerable.Empty<decimal>(),list,0,list.Sum(),epislon);
}
// Define other methods and classes here
bool isClose(IEnumerable<decimal> left,IEnumerable<decimal> right, decimal leftSum,decimal rightSum, decimal epsilon) {
  if (leftSum>=1-epsilon && leftSum<=1+epsilon) return true;
  if (leftSum>1+epsilon) return false;
  if (leftSum+right.Sum()< 1-epsilon) return false;
  if (!right.Any()) return false;

  for (var i=0;i<right.Count();i++) {
    var skip=right.Skip(i);
    var newItem=skip.First();
    if (isClose(left.Concat(skip.Take(1)),skip.Skip(1),leftSum+newItem,rightSum-newItem,epsilon)) return true;
  }
  return false;
}



isClose(new[] {0.7m,0.7m,0.7m},0.001m); // returns false
isClose(new[] {0.7m,0.3m,0.7m},0.001m); //returns true
isClose(new[] {0.777777m,0.2m,0.1m},0.001m); //returns false
isClose(new[] {0.33333m,0.33333m,0.33333m},0.001m); //returns true
```

EDIT 5th Test

```
isClose(new[] {0.4m, 0.5m, 0.6m, 0.3m},0.001m); //returns true
```

Comment: Can you test it with the 5th expected result (see edited question)?

Comment: @DavidB The code does shortcut out the moment a result is found and takes pains to short cut branches that cannot produce a result and so will be better than summing every permutation.  Use of the Take and Skip operators means that list evaluation is deferred until actually needed.  The sum operations are the current slow point

Comment: @DavidB The new update also gets rid of the excessive summing by passing the sums around.

Comment: Yep good job Bob Vale! Exactly what I was looking for..works great!

Comment: depending on the size of your list there are a few optimizations possible. 1st option: convert to array before testing if not aleady List or Array. 2nd, invoke Count() once and use a second overload to carry that, on a true enumerable, Count can be very expensive. 3rd, order the list so you can remove/skip any item that's too large anyways. Then possibly optimize by working choosing the opportune startingpoint.

Answer (score 1):

This is the *subset sum* problem, a special case of the knapsack problem. It's hard (NP-complete). The best known algorithms have exponential complexity. However there are approximate algorithms with polynomial complexity. These answer the question 'is there a subset that sums to 1±ε ?'

- http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~ac/Teach/CS105-Winter05/Notes/nanda-scribe-3.pdf
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem
- Knuth's TAOCP (probably)

Comment: This isn't subset sum problem, this is harder than subset sum (because in subset sum you working with integers, but here you working with floating points).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a rather straightforward, niave, brute force approach.  It won't be efficient, but hopefully it's easier to understand.

```
private const decimal threshold = .001M;

public static bool CloseEnough(decimal first, decimal second, decimal threshold)
{
    return Math.Abs(first - second) < threshold;
}

private static bool SubsetSum(List<decimal> data, int desiredSum)
{

    int numIteratons = (int)Math.Pow(2, data.Count);

    for (int i = 1; i < numIteratons; i++)
    {
        decimal sum = 0;
        int mask = 1;
        for (int j = 0; j < data.Count && sum < desiredSum + threshold; j++)
        {
            if ((i & mask) > 0)
            {
                sum += data[j];
            }
            mask <<= 1;
        }

        if (CloseEnough(sum, desiredSum, threshold))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: I benchmarked the solutions and it turns out that the apparently naive brute force methods were the fastest. I revised my solution to borrow part of yours to come up with the fastest, although this isn't as readable as your original solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static bool SubListAddsTo(this IEnumerable<decimal> source,
  decimal target, decimal tolerance)
{
  decimal lowtarget = target - tolerance;
  decimal hightarget = target + tolerance;
  HashSet<decimal> sums = new HashSet<decimal>();
  sums.Add(0m);
  List<decimal> newSums = new List<decimal>();

  foreach(decimal item in source)
  {
    foreach(decimal oldSum in sums)
    {
      decimal sum = oldSum + item;
      if (sum < lowtarget)
      {
        newSums.Add(sum);//keep trying
      }
      else if (sum < hightarget)
      {
        return true;
      }
      //else { do nothing, discard }
    }
    foreach (decimal newSum in newSums)
    {
      sums.Add(newSum);
    }
    newSums.Clear();
  }
  return false;
}
```

Tested by:

```
List<decimal> list1 = new List<decimal>(){0.7m, 0.7m, 0.7m}; 
List<decimal> list2 = new List<decimal>(){0.7m, 0.3m, 0.7m};
List<decimal> list3= new List<decimal>(){0.777777m, 0.2m, 0.1m};
List<decimal> list4 = new List<decimal>() { 0.33333m, 0.33333m, 0.33333m };
List<decimal> list5 = new List<decimal>() { 0.4m, 0.5m, 0.6m, 0.3m };

Console.WriteLine(list1.SubListAddsTo(1m, 0.001m));  //false
Console.WriteLine(list2.SubListAddsTo(1m, 0.001m));  //true
Console.WriteLine(list3.SubListAddsTo(1m, 0.001m));  //false
Console.WriteLine(list4.SubListAddsTo(1m, 0.001m));  //true
Console.WriteLine(list5.SubListAddsTo(1m, 0.001m));  //true
```

Comment: Can you test it with the 5th expected result (see edited question)?

Comment: It's O(2^n) since the next number can double the number of sums. However, for small lists - not a problem. For lists with many largish values (above target/2), many of those sums are large enough to ignore. Also, exits as soon as the target sum is found instead of checking all combinations.  Lastly, the Hashset discards duplicate sum values.

Answer (score 0):

**edited:** my original code didn't allow for the approximation (0.9999 = 1).

This uses a bitmap of the number of variations to mask the values in the source array in order to brute force all of the variations.

This is about 7.5 times faster than the accepted answer when tested on all five test cases in a million count loop (about 41 seconds vs about 5.5 seconds). It is about twice as fast as David B's sln and about 15% faster than Servy's sln.

```
    public static bool Test(decimal[] list, decimal epsilon)
    {
        var listLength = list.Length;
        var variations = (int)(Math.Pow(2, listLength) - 1);
        var bits = new bool[9];

        for (var variation = variations; variation > 0; variation--)
        {
            decimal sum = 0;

            bits[1] = (variation & 1) == 1;
            bits[2] = (variation & 2) == 2;
            bits[3] = (variation & 4) == 4;
            bits[4] = (variation & 8) == 8;
            bits[5] = (variation & 16) == 16;
            bits[6] = (variation & 32) == 32;
            bits[7] = (variation & 64) == 64;
            bits[8] = (variation & 128) == 128;

            for (var bit = listLength; bit > 0; bit--)
            {
                if (bits[bit])
                {
                    sum += list[bit - 1];
                }
            }

            if (Math.Abs(sum - 1) < epsilon)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

**edit:** this NewTest version is 30% faster than the above version and is over ten times faster than the accepted solution. It removes building the array for coming up with the bitmask in favour of Servy's approach which is where the bulk of the improvement comes from. It also removes the Math.Abs call which gave marginal improvement.

```
    private const decimal Epislon = 0.001m;
    private const decimal Upper = 1 + Epislon;
    private const decimal Lower = 1 - Epislon;

    private static bool NewTest(decimal[] list)
    {
        var listLength = list.Length;
        var variations = (int)(Math.Pow(2, listLength) - 1);

        for (var variation = variations; variation > 0; variation--)
        {
            decimal sum = 0;
            int mask = 1;

            for (var bit = listLength; bit > 0; bit--)
            {
                if ((variation & mask) == mask)
                {
                    sum += list[bit - 1];
                }
                mask <<= 1;
            }

            if (sum > Lower && sum < Upper)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```